# opening the appbar in metro style apps using binding property

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

My main page has the appbar and it is shared across different pages. I wrote the following code to open the appbar on the click of a gridview item.

XAML

```
<AppBar Opened="AppBar_Opened" IsOpen="{Binding IsAppBarOpen}">
```

Back end

```
private void Clock_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{            
    App.ViewModel.SelectedClock = (Clock)ThemeGridView.SelectedItem;
    App.WorldViewModel.IsAppBarOpen = true;                  
}

 private void ThemeGridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        App.ViewModel.SelectedClock = (Clock)ThemeGridView.SelectedItem;
        App.WorldViewModel.IsAppBarOpen = true;
    }
```

WorldViewModel

```
private bool _IsAppBarOpen;

public bool IsAppBarOpen
{
   get { return _IsAppBarOpen; }
   set { base.SetProperty(ref _IsAppBarOpen, value); }
}
```

GridView XAML

```
<GridView
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1"


         x:Name="ThemeGridView"                    
                ItemsSource="{Binding Clocks}" 
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource WorldClockTemplate}"
                SelectionChanged="Clock_SelectionChanged"
                SelectionMode="None"
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                ItemClick="ThemeGridView_ItemClick"
                >
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <WrapGrid />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
```

But the appbar is not popping up when i select the gridview item. There is no binding error so its really mysterious!

Comment: can you post definition of your gridview and item tapped event ?

Comment: can you add the DataContext in your xaml? Maybe your binding is wrong. On the other side: I think you should not do that, because does not expect that the appbar opens when clicking in the UI. What do you want to do? AppBar will be invoked when clicking right or with a swipe.

Comment: @Fixus I have added the definition for the gridview. And i think the SelectionChangedEvent works the same as item tapped right? I tried it with right tapped event also but it didnt work.

Comment: @Raubi I put the same binding to a text block just to check if the binding is happening and the text block is displaying the true value. I think IsOpen property is being set to true but still the appbar is not opening....dunno y!

And the appbar contains buttons like add and remove, so when i select an item i want the appbar to immediately popup so that users can remove that item. I dont want users to select the item and then right tap everytime......the appbar should automaticcally popup when  the user selects an item

Comment: does the normal tap even (left tap) works ?

Comment: @user1697150 I think this is not the intention of the appbar. The appbar hides, like a context menu, more not so important functions from the user. If he want to do something more, he will rightclick and get the appbar. Well, it is a matter of context, but maybe you should think about this, because this is not the standard behaviour of a win rt app.

Comment: Sorry but it is the standard behaviour in a Win RT app....the app bar is used to display all the actions u want to perform on any items u have on the screen. Anyways please check the weather app on WIndows8.....it has the same functionality! When a city is selected, the appbar immediately pops up with buttons like "pin to taskbar" or "remove" etc

Comment: @Fixus The normal right tap works......that is if u right tap anywhere on the screen except the item the appbar is opened but i want the appbar to be opened when the item is selected

Comment: @Bitsian try by adding ' IsItemClickEnabled="True"' to your GridView definition

Comment: @Fixus Thanks for the suggestion but it didnt work even then!! :(

Comment: @Bitsian try creating same thing for left click. If it works we`ll think what i can mean

Comment: @Fixus I handled the itemClick event and its still not working!

Comment: add more code. show me your current definition of gridview and the item click method. Remember that you need to set IsItemClickEnabled to handle left click

Comment: I have edited the question and showed the gridview and item click method! I have a feeling the problem is not because of gridview, it has got to do something with the appbar because when i put the binding that i put for IsOpen property of appbar to a textblock, the textblock was showing true when i select the item!

Answer (score 3):

There is not way to bind IsOpen property [according the msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.isopen):

> **Note**  Binding to the `IsOpen` property doesn't have the expected results
>   because the `PropertyChanged` notification doesn't occur when the
>   property is set.

Answer (score 1):

```
<AppBar Opened="AppBar_Opened" IsOpen="{Binding IsAppBarOpen, **Mode=TwoWay**}">
```

Comment: Its a good suggestion but strangely its still not working!! :(

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. I use MVVM Light Toolkit.

```
public bool AppBarIsOpen
{
    get { return this._appBarIsOpen; }

    set
    {
        if (this._appBarIsOpen == value) { return; }

        this._appBarIsOpen = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("AppBarIsOpen"); // without INotifyPropertyChanged it doesn't work
    }
}


<AppBar
    IsSticky="True"
    IsOpen="{Binding Path=AppBarIsOpen, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Roman Weisert's answer correctly states the likely reason for it not working, although you also must make the binding two-way as Zack Weiner suggested (I'm not sure the reason for the latter since the binding is not working in the target-to-source direction anyway).  The current value of `AppBar.IsOpen` may not be reflected by `IsAppBarOpen` of your view-model.  When that's the case, and you try updating the value, it's possible that no `PropertyChanged` event is raised since you may not actually be updating a value.  Instead, you may be just setting the value from `false` to `false` or from `true` to `true`.  Most `SetProperty` method implementations do not raise the `PropertyChanged` event unless there is an actual change, and I presume yours is the same.

To fix the problem, consider modifying your view-model as follows:

```
public bool IsAppBarOpen
{
    get { return _IsAppBarOpen; } //changes initiated from UI not reflected
    set //not updated from UI
    {
        _IsAppBarOpen = value;
        base.OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
bool _IsAppBarOpen;
```

The notable difference from your view-model's code, is that `SetProperty` is not called here so `PropertyChanged` is raised even when the backing store equals the newly introduced value.  In case your base class differs, note that mine has an `OnPropertyChanged` method with the signature

```
void OnPropertyChanged( [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null )
```

that serves to raise the `PropertyChanged` event.

I can see from your use of the code-behind, though, that you are not really following MVVM.  If MVVM is not a concern to you, then you could forgo the `IsAppBarOpen` property altogether and just directly set `AppBar.IsOpen`.  As someone who religiously adheres to MVVM, however, I do not recommend that you further head in that (sinful) direction.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and using Caliburn Micro for WinRT and with this code worked for me:

```
<AppBar IsOpen="{Binding AppBarsOpen}" Name="MainAppBar" Padding="10,0,10,0" AutomationProperties.Name="Bottom App Bar">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="LeftPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Button Name="ShowFlyout"  Style="{StaticResource BookmarksAppBarButtonStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="RightPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource SaveAppBarButtonStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</AppBar>
```

And that's your property in ViewModel:

```
public bool AppBarsOpen
{
    get { return _appBarsOpen; }
    set
    {
        if (value.Equals(_appBarsOpen)) return;
        _appBarsOpen = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => AppBarsOpen);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, solved it by adding the Closed event and updating the ViewModel from the code behind. Saw no other way since TwoWay binding was not working as Roman pointed out.

XAML

```
<AppBar x:Name="BottomAppBar1"
                AutomationProperties.Name="Bottom App Bar"
                Closed="BottomAppBar1_Closed"
                IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay}"
                IsSticky="True">
```

C# Code behind

```
private void BottomAppBar1_Closed(object sender, object e)
{
  MainViewModel vm = this.DataContext as MainViewModel;
  vm.IsOpen = false;
}
```

C# MainViewModel

```
public const string IsOpenPropertyName = "IsOpen";

private bool isOpen = false;

/// <summary>
/// Sets and gets the IsOpen property.
/// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
/// </summary>
public bool IsOpen
{
  get
  {
    return isOpen;
  }
  set
  {
    RaisePropertyChanging(IsOpenPropertyName);
    isOpen = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(IsOpenPropertyName);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind both IsOpen and IsSticky two way because otherwise you will get problems with for example having to tap two time to unselect an item (once to close the app bar and once for unselecting) and also it's the will help having your app bar behave more standarly (will prevent the app bar to pop down on tap when an item is selected). 
To show the app bar you will need to do the following (the order is important):

```
this.IsAppBarSticky = true;
this.IsAppBarOpen = true;
```

and to hide it, do the following:

```
this.IsAppBarSticky = false;
this.IsAppBarOpen = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make this work without having to use a codebehind handler for app bar closed event:

```
public class AppBarClosedCommand
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command", typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(AppBarClosedCommand), new PropertyMetadata(null, CommandPropertyChanged));


    public static void SetCommand(DependencyObject attached, ICommand value)
    {
        attached.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }


    public static ICommand GetCommand(DependencyObject attached)
    {
        return (ICommand)attached.GetValue(CommandProperty);
    }


    private static void CommandPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Attach click handler
        (d as AppBar).Closed += AppBar_onClose;
    }


    private static void AppBar_onClose(object sender, object e)
    {
        // Get GridView
        var appBar = (sender as AppBar);


        // Get command
        ICommand command = GetCommand(appBar);


        // Execute command
        command.Execute(e);
    }
}
```

then in the XAML you can use it like :

```
common:AppBarClosedCommand.Command="{Binding AppBarClosedCommand}"
```

with the command function looking like:

```
public void OnAppBarClosed()
    {
        AppBarOpen = false;
    }
```