# Windows Store Apps: Bind App bar IsOpen property to ListView Selected Item

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a Page with a ListView and an AppBar. I want to make sure that the AppBar cannot be opened/visible unless the ListViews' selected item is not null.

so I implemented the AppBar like this:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
        <AppBar x:Name="bottomAppBar" Padding="10,0,10,0">
            <AppBar.IsOpen>
                <Binding ElementName="MyGrid" Path="SelectedItem" Converter="{StaticResource ValueToBooleanConverter}"/>
            </AppBar.IsOpen>
        </AppBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
```

**ValueToBooleanConverter** is an IValueConverter that checks that returns a boolean based on if the SelectedItem of the GridView is null or not.

what happens is the AppBar appears even if the GridView Selected Item is null.

what can be wrong here ?

Comment: There are [precedence rules that govern dependency property values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) that could be in play here. That said, are you sure you want to create such behavior? This is a rather subjective, but I'd say it may not be intuitive to a user that the app bar appears sometimes and not others. Perhaps bind the enablement of the various commands on the app bar to the selected state and even include some text on the bar when there is no selection to give the user a cue as to how to enable the various features?

Comment: Thanks Neil. I've got a list of items, and buttons which become visible when an item is selected. I thought it would be smart to put those buttons in the app bar, and then open it when an item is selected. It turns out to be quite hard to do this, and I've been looking everywhare for a solution in XAML. Now, if I understand you correctly, you are saying that this is not a good idea at all. Keep the app bar for one set of commands, and don't change it when an item is selected. I agree - the users will find this confusing. Also, thanks for the link on precedence rules for dependency property.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it and it seems, that bindings don't work with `AppBar.IsOpen`.

I bound a `Button.IsEnabled` to `GridView.SelectedItem` as well, and the button was correctly set to `false`, but `AppBar.IsOpen` was not, the converter was only called once for the button binding.

It might have something to do with this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.isopen

> **Note**  Binding to the IsOpen property doesn't have the expected results because the PropertyChanged notification doesn't occur when the property is set.

Though I thought that meant only the other direction.
(edit: Here is a simialar post: [opening the appbar in metro style apps using binding property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582497/opening-the-appbar-in-metro-style-apps-using-binding-property))

Here is the code I used:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar IsOpen="{Binding SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource ObjectToBooleanConverter}, ElementName=gridView}"
            IsSticky="True"
            Background="#E5F50000" />
</common:LayoutAwarePage.BottomAppBar>


<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <GridView x:Name="gridView"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
              Margin="0"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Width="469">
        <Button Content="asdf" />
        <Button Content="asdf" />
        <Button Content="asdf" />
    </GridView>
    <Button x:Name="bsetnull"
            Content="setnull"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="78,10,0,0"
            Grid.Row="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Tapped="bsetnull_Tapped"/>
    <Button x:Name="bsettoone"
            Content="settoone"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="78,71,0,0"
            Grid.Row="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Tapped="bsettoone_Tapped"/>
    <Button Content="Button"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="78,147,0,0"
            Grid.Row="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource ObjectToBooleanConverter}, ElementName=gridView}" />

</Grid>
```

And the converter

```
public class ObjectToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind Visibility property with SelectedItem and have converter which collapse the item in case of null value.. Also I doubt in case of selectedItem being null converter getting called. Just recheck and it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You already posted the microsoft link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.isopen), so maybe you provide a property on your own to bind to and set it in the Opened and Closed events of the appbar.